# How can i make gmail send me HTTP request everytime i get new message

Tags: php, ajax, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I am creating a laravel app to manage my Gmail using google client api to manage my customers and connect them with the emplyees

In my app there is last_interaction attribute to each client that changes everytime they get or send emails to me

I want gmail to send my app every new message i get using HTTP request so that i can update this attribute in my database

Can u help?

By the way, I looked for an event listener to do that in google app script but i couldn't find any

I looked for an event listener to do that in google app script but i couldn't find any

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to do this with only apps script. You would need [Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). Another alternative, which can be done in Apps script, is to use triggers to poll the gmail server every few minutes.